# How does a Redis Server work with client side script?

Tags: javascript, php, python, redis, publish-subscribe

I am relatively new to Redis as a NoSql server solution having programmed my databases primarily with php in conjunction with jquery ajax calls. I'm sure some programmers making the transition would find it helpful to know how polling compares to pub sub and how it is implemented.

The problem I had was the confusion over how redis actually works with client side scripting. Is it like a persistent event listener built into the client? And how does the client actually interface with the server itself.

Is redis like a php class with functions that can be called by ajax requests or is it totally server side (I haven't seen much client side examples). From my understanding, redis is a server side script that emits data every time it changes.

Can someone please clear up the server-client interaction in terms of Javascript or any other client side language?